# Problems removeChild of many elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a function that creates div with the class `animate` (which uses css3 animations) and then deletes it when `webKitAnimationEnd` triggers. The problem comes when i have multiple divs: the function only deletes the first one, but fails with the others, causing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChild' of null`.

```
function msg(x) {
    cnt = document.getElementsByClassName("animate").length;
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = x;
    div.className = "animate";
    div.style.bottom = (cnt) * 30 + "px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(div);
    div.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with my code reproducing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p5HR3/3/

I suspect the functions doesn't know which div to delete when there are many of them. What could i do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you do realise, webKitAnimationEnd works only on chrome/safari?

Comment: Try not using global variables for everything, the `var` keyword is there for a reason.

Comment: @LorDex Yes i do. I was just testing it on my browser. If you're saying that it won't work for other people here, well you just have to change some lines.

Comment: @adeneo I know, it's just prototype code.

Comment: @PTAC - You're not getting it, it wasn't a suggestion, `div` ends up being `window.div`, and on every iteration you're overwriting it so you end up with trying to remove the last `div` nine times, which fails. Using the `var` keyword solves the issue

Comment: @adeneo I got it now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change event handler code to:

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

In that case `this` will point to the correct div, which fired an event.

P.S.: `onClick="for(i=0;i<10;i++){msg('message n.'+i);}"` - this is bad. Do not use inline Javascript.

Comment: The global variables being used in the OP's code are bad and should also be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your variables be local variables (with `var` in front of their first use) so they will be unique to each function invocation.  As you have them now, they are global variables so they are all sharing one copy of the variable and thus only one div is removed.

Make it this:

```
function msg(x) {
    var cnt = document.getElementsByClassName("animate").length;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = x;
    div.className = "animate";
    div.style.bottom = (cnt) * 30 + "px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(div);
    div.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });
}
```

---

FYI, "implicit" global variables like you were using are a horrible source of bugs in javascript code.  All variables should be explicitly declared as global or declared as local (preferably local unless you must use a global variable) and you will not be bitten by this implicit global problem again.

---

FYI, in this particular case, you could have also solve your problem like this by using `this` to reference the node that received the "webkitAnimationEnd" event, but you still should not be using the implicit globals so that should be cleaned up too:

```
function msg(x) {
    var cnt = document.getElementsByClassName("animate").length;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = x;
    div.className = "animate";
    div.style.bottom = (cnt) * 30 + "px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(div);
    div.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
        // the this ptr will contain a reference to the node that
        // received the webkitAnimationEnd event
        this.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });
}
```